# How to add a row in grid at runtime using Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, grid

I am new to Windows Phone 7. I want to generate a list of students who are registered from another page. I want to display students list as a record into a grid

My code are as following:

xaml code:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ShowGridLines="True" Width="400" Height="200" Name="GridStud">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0">Registered Student List</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Id</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">Full Name</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">Contact</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3">Email</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4">Stream</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5">Delete</TextBlock>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Name="txtId" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Name="txtName" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Name="txtContact" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Name="txtEmail" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Name="txtStream" />
                <Button FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5" Name="btnDelete">Delete</Button>

                <TextBlock FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="4">Total Students: 3</TextBlock>

            </Grid>
```

CS Code:

```
private void PivotItem_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            StreamReader sr = null;
            try
            {
                sr = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Data\\inquiry.json", FileMode.Open, isf));


                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var stud = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(sr.ReadLine());

                    txtId.Text += "\t" + stud.Id;
                    txtName.Text += "\t" + stud.Name;
                    txtContact.Text += "\t" + stud.Contact;
                    txtEmail.Text += "\t" + stud.Email;
                    txtStream.Text += "\t" + stud.Stream;
                }

                sr.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

All registered records are display, but in a single row. I want to display those records in a different row, and also generate a run time grid row.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public ObservableCollection<StudentListModel> StudentListItems { get; private set; }
```

Initialize ObservableCollection. And You have to specify fields in the StudentListModel Class. Like Follows

```
  private long? _id;
        public long? Id
        {
            get
            {
                return _id;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _id)
                {
                    _id = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
                }
            }
        }
```

And In constructor of your PhoneApplicationPage, you have to create StudentListItems like below

```
 public StudentList()
   {

    this.StudentListItems = new ObservableCollection<StudentListModel>();

    }
```

After That You have to Assign Value to the collection like below. Here I retrieve the values from the database.

```
 foreach (var dri in getStudentList)
                {
     this.StudentListItems.Add(new StudentListModel()
                            {
                                Id= dri.Id,
                                Name= dri.Name,
                                Contact= dri.Contact,
                                Email=  dri.Email,

                            });
}
```

And you have to set it into Listbox.

```
viewStudentList.ItemsSource = StudentListItems;
```

Your View should be As Follows. It give the output list.

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"   Name="viewStudentList" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="7,38,-7,-108" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="40">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Margin="0,0,290,-22" TextAlignment="Left" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"  Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Margin="60,0,138,-22" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Contact}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Margin="150,0,12,-22" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Email}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Margin="355,0,12,-22" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: I am using vs 2010..  following error display..Error 1 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'PhoneApp1.Student' because 'PhoneApp1.Student' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Error 2 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I am trying to add below code... above error are comes....... var stud = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(sr.ReadLine());

                foreach (var dri in stud)
                {
                    this.lstItem.Add(new Student()
                    {
                        Id = dri.Id,
                        Name = dri.Name,
                        Contact = dri.Contact,
                        Email = dri.Email,

                    });
                }

Comment: I am using vs 2010 version with windows phone 7